# Getting schema virtual attributes from Mongoose model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i know that mongoose has a 'paths' property that can be accessed from model (without no need to an instance) and returns the schema attributes. The problem is that 'paths' does not return virtual attributes. is there a way to return virtual attributes from the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `model.schema.paths` you mentioned, there is another object at `model.schema.virtuals` that contains all virtual attributes (including the default `.id` attribute).